# Converting Int to String in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a column of zip codes from int to string in a pandas dataframe. However, it keeps adding a decimal point to the zip codes when converting to strings. 78521 becomes 78521.0 for example. How do I convert the column to a string without adding a decimal?

Comment: How are you attempting to do it now? Are they actually `int` or are they `float` values which are close to an integer? Do you have some data and code that's exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: So it is currently an int. For the code, I am saying: df['add_zip5'] = df['add_zip5'].astype(str)

Comment: Can you come up with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I just made a simple dataframe full of integers on my end and they printed just fine with no trailing decimals.

Comment: Oh I think it is in fact a float, which is why it has a decimal

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways that I can think of in pandas to do so

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].apply(str)
```

or

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str)
```

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

Example

```
>>> data = {'Product': ['ABC','DDD','XYZ'],
          'Zipcode': [78521,78522,78523]
        }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df['Zipcode'] = df['Zipcode'].apply(str)
>>> df
  Product Zipcode
0     ABC   78521
1     DDD   78522
2     XYZ   78523
```